# C# is there anyway to instruct a code block to finish processing before the app gets shut down?

Tags: c#

I know this won't work in all scenarios, but please keep in mind the following 3 scenarios:

1. An IIS reset - if the code is running inside IIS
2. A Server restart or shut down
3. User closes the app (if its a Windows form or Console App).

Lets say I have a code block that runs a loop. Is there a way to ensure at least that the current loop item gets processed before the app shuts down.

Like this...

Loop runs: 100 items, app gets shutdown (for reasons above), app is busy with item in loop 53 for example. It first finishes all code for that item between the foreach... and then allows the app to gracefully shutdown.

Is this type of thing possible?

Comment: Can't you undo all the 53 items instead? With transactions

Comment: @OskarKjellin the problem is not about the completed 52 items. Rather it is about the 53rd item that does for example 10 units of work. In different systems. Not just SQL. If 3-4 items of work get finished, and app shuts down, then there is no way to easily get back to that item without loads of code to ensure restartability. I am looking for a more OOB c# approach to the problem.

Comment: Indeed you could be in a situation with 'exceptional' circumstances meaning that continuing could result in corrupt information or continual errors. Although undoing the action maybe difficult it would be recommended as anything running as a final process should either tidy up or 'roll-back' as opposed to finishing what has happened. Especially as for closing reasons you suggested can be done because there is a problem meaning you can't reliable assume that continuing is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing I would do but If it is ok to abuse the system you might be able to use the [CriticalFinalizerObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx)

It is guaranteed to execute

> even in situations where the CLR forcibly unloads an application domain or aborts a thread

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think so. You are stuck in front of windows. Windows take that kind of decisions for you.. IF somebody is shutting down the pc, then you are just shut down. This is the same scenario as if they where a power failure. What will you do in that case?

Comment: Power failures are one thing. IIS resets or a user clicking the close button are more controlled scenarios.

Comment: sure, but for the kind of code you are running, is the same scenario... I would add a flag to every change, and for the final step (after all is procesing), I will update that flag to ok, meaning that all this happens ok. something like building a custom transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In most apps you can handle close event and not allow it but you can't do anything when user decides to kill your process. So i would say that its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For a normal application: While your code is running in a foreground thread (not ThreadPool or Thread.IsBackground == true) it will not be aborted mid-execution, unless the user forcibly quits the process.

If you are running your loop in a background thread, you can try handling the exit event of the application, waiting for the loop to finish or at least reach a stable state before being aborted.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this. using a try catch and finally in the static void Main
Here even if you end task the application, finally will run. not sure about power failure.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I run always.");
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: LOL, "not sure about power failure" => I guess you're joking, right??

Comment: you never guess wrong my dear friend. I was just trying to imitate others doubt. because for power failures you need Power Generator but not code generators. LOL :-)